# Trying to delete/update child elements while keeping parent data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, sql-delete

I have 3 tables in a chain, the top one being a 'Corridor' `@Entity`, the bottom being `Segment` `@Entity`, the middle being created via `@JoinTable`, with a `ManyToMany` relationship between the id columns in two other tables. This one is called `CorridorSegments`

I am trying to find a way to keep the corridor data, and delete all of the `segments` rows and `corridor_segments` rows that are in the database related to the `corridor` row. I then intend to replace them. So it's pretty much an update process, keeping the original data in the top 'corridor' table and linking it to new entries.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "corridor")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "corridor")
public class Corridor implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "text_identifier", nullable = false)
    private String textIdentifier;

    @ManyToOne
    private Jurisdiction jurisdiction;
    //etc., etc., getters, setters, constructors, basic Entity class
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "segment")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Segment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "sequence", nullable = false)
    private Long sequence;


    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    //etc., etc., getters, setters, constructors, basic Entity class
}
```

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "corridor_segments",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="corridor_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="segment_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Set<Segment> segments = new HashSet<>();
```

I can save new entries to the segments table through my repository class that extends the JPARepository interface, using a simple `segmentRepository.save(segment);` But when I try to use the built in `segmentRepository.delete();`, it doesn't work.

I think it might be because I need to detach the relationships before the deletes will work, or change how that middle table is structured, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions on how I can delete the data in the table and replace them? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I think you can probably set the `segments` to emptyList and save it then set the `segements` to however you want to then save it again .

Comment: Could you fix you code snippets, please? current both classes never end and `Segement` seems to contain a self reference, which does not fit the description in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the `Corridor` for which you want to delete all `Segment` entries.

From it iterate over the referenced `Segment` instances.
For each on you need to remove it from all `Corridor` instances it is in.
So it is no longer referenced.
Then you can delete it using the `delete` operation on a `SegementRepository`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried loading it, then removing all the segments from the corridor. 
The debugger showed 0 segments in the loaded corridor object.
I then did the delete on the segmentRepository, but when I checked, everything was still the same.
I'm guessing the only reason that would happen is if there was still an open reference to the objects in the database?
I also tried the suggestion above where I overwrote the corridor object with an empty list, then did a save operation to the segmentRepository, but nothing changed then either.

Comment: Sounds like your changes weren't flushed and committed. Makes sure all of the above happens in a transaction and the check happens after the transaction.

Comment: You're right! That was what was missing all along. flushing after clearing out those segments did the trick. Thanks for your help